# Rejecting data enty in google sheet in a column beyond a limit set

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I want to restrict the number of entries in a column in a google spread sheet. I have not found answers in the community posts

Comment: Go to data validation. Share a spreadsheet in needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Rejecting data enty in google sheet in a column beyond a limit set

example... so only entries with less than 10 characters are allowed:

```
=LEN(A2)<10
```

[image]